# dynamically generate tests based on command line arguments

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, fixtures

I want to dynamically generate test functions based on presence or absence of command line argument.
I have command line argument --connection where I specify interface. For example --connection "com5". I have also set of tests to be run only on SW (without HW) and set of tests to be run on HW.
Here is the problem: When I do not pass argument --connection, I want to run only SW-related tests (for example only 3 tests), HW-specific will be skipped (this is handled by fixture connection). When I specify connection (for example --connection "com1") I want to run all tests (both HW and SW-specific)- 3 SW tests + 5 HW tests all together.
Here is the snippet of code. My part of confest.py to handle fixture:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--connection",
        action="store",
        help="Provide interface parameters",
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def connection(request):
    if not request.config.getoption("--connection"):
        pytest.skip("need to provide connection")
    return request.config.getoption("--connection")
```

Example of tests:

```
def test_command_sw():
    command= "some-command"
    result = run_command(command)
    assert result == 0


def test_command_sw(connection):
    command= f"{connection} some-command"
    result = run_command(command)
    assert result == 0
```

I have tried using pytest_generate_tests:

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    option_value = metafunc.config.option.name
    if option_value is not None:
        metafunc.fixturenames.insert(0, 'connection')
```

Where I insert fixture based presence of command line option. But in this case, the amount of test is settled and can't be changed. For example always there will be 8 tests all together (no dynamic creation).
Thanks in advance for any ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Can you show the part about the 3 SW and the 5 HW tests? As I don't think I'm following.

Comment: I don't understand which tests do you want to create dynamically. From your description it looks as if this already works as intended. Can you elaborate on the desired result?